# Bourbon Neat 1 - make elements span the gutter

Tags: css, grid, bourbon, neat

I keep receiving designs whereby the designer has followed a grid, but occasionally the elements line up to the other side of the gutter, or 2 elements meet halfway though a column. Please see the image - the first row shows normal conformity to a grid, the second row shows some of the issues.

Using Bourbon Neat 1.0 (not 2), how can I replicate these sizes (other than telling our designer not to do it)? I imagine some kind of mixin like @include span-right-gutter() but maybe I'm not searching for the right things.

Also - now that 2.0 is out I can't find any docs for 1.0 - where are the docs?!

Any help appreciated, thanks.

[image: grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can access column and gutter widths directly like:

`width: flex-grid(7) + flex-gutter(12);`

Answer (score 0):

To answer one of your questions, you can find older docs at http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/1.8.0/

[image]

Comment: I feel like this coulda been left as a comment